# Can you do edge detection of a DepthFrame in Kinect SDK (WPF, C#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, kinect-sdk, edge-detection

I've processed my depth frame to byte array which is a particular color for a user and black otherwise. This byte array (depthColorImage) is converted to a Bitmap using the following code:

```
public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this byte[] data, int width, int height, PixelFormat format)
        {
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, format);
            var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
            new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            bitmap.PixelFormat);
            Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, data.Length);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            return bitmap;
        }
```

I've then tried to apply single matrix convolution using the code found [here](https://softwarebydefault.com/2013/05/11/image-edge-detection/).

I convert the resultant bitmap back to bitmapsource using the code:

```
public static Media.Imaging.BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            if (bitmap == null) return null;
            IntPtr ptr = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            var source  =System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            ptr,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            DeleteObject(ptr);
            return source;
        }
```

Finally I try to display this by using:

```
this.depthImage.Source = depthColorImage.ToBitmap(depthFrame.Width, depthFrame.Height,PixelFormats.Bgr32).ConvolutionFilter().ToBitmapSource();
```

But my Window just hangs. If I take out the convolution filter it works just fine. I'm a beginner to C# and I'm looking into openCV but I was wondering if there is something wrong with my code or is it something else all together?